# How to listen conditionally for update in a collection of room messages (firestore)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to listen for collection of rooms of last 50 messages. I mean to listen for every room messages but only 50 last messages of every room.

```
rooms/room1/messages/message1
                    /message2
                    /message...

      room2/messages/message1
                    /message2
                    /message...

      room...
```

Now How can I listen to just last `50` `rooms` messages when the `conditional_var===true` and not listen when `conditional_var===false`. Here the `conditional_var` will be changed sometime.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly what you ask, if you "want to listen for collection of rooms of last 50 messages" you should set up a listener on a query which sort you records by creation timestamp, in descending order, and limit them to 50.

Something like the following:

```
var roomsListener = db.collection("rooms/room1/messages").orderBy("creationDate", "desc").limit(50)
        .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
            var docs = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                docs.push(doc.data().anyField);
            });
            console.log("Current values: ", docs.join(", "));
        });
```

If you want to stop listening because `conditional_var===false`, just detach the listener as shown in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener), and as follows:

```
roomsListener();
```

Since the listener "can be cancelled by calling the function that is returned when onSnapshot is called", see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#on-snapshot.

---

**Update following your comment:**

If you want to do the same but for multiple collections, just use a [Collection Group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#collection-group-query), as follows

```
var roomsListener = db.collectionGroup("messages").orderBy("creationDate", "desc").limit(50)
        .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
            var docs = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                docs.push(doc.data().anyField);
            });
            console.log("Current values: ", docs.join(", "));
        });
```

Note that you need to create a specific index for the Collection Group query. As explained in this [blog article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html), the first time you will trigger the listener "the client SDK will give you an error message, because the collection group index hasn't been created yet. But along with this error message there is a URL that you can follow to fix it".

---

To re-activate (i.e. re-attach) the listener, just call again `onSnapshot` on the query.

Here is a very simple JavaScript code with two functions that will in-turn attach or detach the listener. You should most probably make this code more robust, but it shows how you could do.

```
var listener = null;

function attachListener() {
    listener = db.collectionGroup("messages").orderBy("creationDate", "desc").limit(50)
        .onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
            var docs = [];
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                docs.push(doc.data().anyField);
            });
            console.log("Current values: ", docs.join(", "));
        });
}


function detachListener() {
    if (listener != null) {
        listener();
    }
}
```

Comment: THank you so much, you are answered correctly, But here I have joined multiple rooms so I am listening to multiple collections, and Also if I detach it, then how can listen again?

Comment: thank you could you please when I use `collectionGroup` then how can I specify the rooms.

Comment: You have to define pass to CollectionGroup the name of the **collections** you want to listen to. It is not clear from your question which exact collections you need to listen to. If the collections have different names you will not be able to use CollectionGroup.

Comment: Thank you, the collection name is same which it is `messages` but every collection is under different room like this `rooms/room1/messages/message1, rooms/room2/messages/message1, rooms/room3/messages/message1`

Comment: It should work. Just give some tries to understand how exactly it works. The documentation is also an element to read carefully: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#collection-group-query

Comment: Thank you, I will accept it when it solved my problem.
Right now the problem is how to listen to same collection under different rooms